# Error when copying files between document libraries in Windows Explorer [SP2010]

Tags: 2010, document-library, document, copy-and-paste, open-with-explorer

Two of our users receive an error message each time they try to copy a file between two document libraries with Open with Explorer in Sharepoint 2010.
The document libraries are on seperate sites but are part of the same site collection.
Other users can copy/paste files between these document libraries just fine.

[image]

Comment: Please check the Event Viewer for log. you will find the problem over there

Comment: Please refer this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx